# login/logout problem in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question. 
I have a website in which i am giving security like login id and password( as usual). No what i want is that, 
1) I don't want to allow a single user to login in different machine at the same time. 
2) For this i am using a column in database which is keeping the current status of user(i.e. loging/logout). I am allowing user to login only when has session has not closed and status is login. 
3) So my problem is that when i am logging out manually. it is closing the session as well as updating the database with status "logout".
4) but when i am closing the window from Cross buttonat top right corner. it is closing the ssion but table data is still "login". so later on i can't be able to login into the same user.
5) So how could i solve this problem.
Please help me!

Comment: Describe a situation which led you to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I don't want to allow a single user
>   to login in different machine at the
>   same time.

Every time a user tries to login, check if a session has already been set. You can do this by saving a hash of a unix time stamp to the database that is associated with the user as well as set the hash to the session every time a user logins. Once the user logins again, you'll create a new hash which will overwrite the old hash in the database.

Then in all your protected files, you can compare the session hash variable to the one in the database. If it doesn't match, log the user out- but the new login instance will still stay active.

> 2 + 3 + 4) For this i am using a
>   column in database which is keeping
>   the current status of user(i.e.
>   loging/logout). I am allowing user to
>   login only when has session has not
>   closed and status is login. So my
>   problem is that when i am logging out
>   manually. it is closing the session as
>   well as updating the database with
>   status "logout".but when i am closing
>   the window from Cross buttonat top
>   right corner. it is closing the ssion
>   but table data is still "login". so
>   later on i can't be able to login into
>   the same user.

For this, you have to save a last active unix time stamp. You will also have to come up with amount of time before you "logout" the user- this is usually an hour or 3600 seconds. Either using a cron job or an include file on certain pages, you can check the times for the users and compare them doing `if(time - last_active_time > 3600){your_logout_func();}`

5) So how could i solve this problem. Please help me!

Doing that above should fix your problems, but of course there are many ways to solve it :)

Answer (score 3):

Do it another way.
Don't forbid access. Just manually log the previous one out.
Like ICQ or other smart enough messengers do.

To do so, keep the session id in the user's table. Once it got changed - prompt for login.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion....
This solution is ok for one machine only. where a user is login and logout using a single machine.
But suppose this operation is going to be performmed on different machines then a problem will areise. And that problem is

if an unauthorized user try to login with right uid and password. It make logout to authentic user(if he/she is logged in at that time).
This think i don't want to do.
I want to make first user login without interruption.

Comment: @user356170 don't be silly. It doesn't matter how many machines involved. And where, for the god's sake, unauthorized users will get uid and pass?

Comment: And with what you want to do : imagine the valid user logout. An attacker with uid and pass log in. Then the valid user can not log in anymore.
The problem is not the good behind prevented from loging in or not. It's the user losing his password.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function logout(){
window.open("http://www.yoursite.com/logout.php","_blank");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onunload="logout()">
</body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if user turns javascript off?

Comment: this function would get call every time user go off the page, the problem will arise when user go to another pages through links

Comment: Thanks tazphoneix for your suggestion...
But points arised by "Ondresj Slintak" and "nik" is considerable.
This two problem is really big problem, so that i couldn't able to identify the exact status of user.

Thanx to "Ondrrj Slintak" and "nik" to put such condition in front of viewer. Thanx a lot.

Please give some more fullproof solution.
Thanx for viewers to see this quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a cron job running that will periodically check your user's status.  For instance, if the last time the user "did something" is too far away, then you could have your script log the user out.

This would involve tracking the user's status as well...maybe a simple table that checks page views.

Comment: Idea is good. but thing is that when a user close the browser, we can not make any changes in database.
So it is difficult to know when did we logout last time.

Finally i decided to do one thing.
I will make logout of previous session whenver a new session request for login.